# Classifying / labeling polygonal meshes

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Being relatively new to machine learning I am trying to use the simplest algorithm to classify mesh objects. I can have the mesh objects in any familiar file type such as STL, OBJ, PLY, FBX etc. I should have enough training data as well as validation data.

My question is where do I start? how is the mesh converted into some form of a shape that one of the common machine learning libraries (e.g. tensorflow, libsvm) can read?